# what is the "behaviorConfiguration" attribute of service?

Tags: wcf

what is the "behaviorConfiguration" attribute of service?

```
<services>
      <service name="WcfServiceNetMSMQ.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfServiceNetMSMQ.Service1Behavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8010/WcfServiceNetMSMQ/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address ="net.msmq://localhost/private/myqueue" binding="netMsmqBinding" contract="WcfServiceNetMSMQ.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is a reference to another configuration section:

```
<behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="WcfServiceNetMSMQ.Service1Behavior">

      </behaviors>
   </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Where this section contains some global configuration for the whole service.

Answer (score 51):

There are 3 important sections when you configure a WCF service.

1) Defining the Services:

```
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SOAPRESTDemoBehavior" name="SOAPRESTDemo">
        <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="SOAPRESTDemoEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ISOAPRESTDemo" />
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ISOAPRESTDemo" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

NOTE the value of behaviorConfiguration is a reference to a section further on in the config see below...

2) Defining the 'Service Behaviours'

```
 <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SOAPRESTDemoBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
```

3) Defining the 'Endpoint Behaviours'

```
<endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SOAPRESTDemoEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
```

All 3 sections are the basics for what you need to set up a service (although this can be done programatically).

With regard to your question the behaviorConfiguration section relates to point 2 and 3 in my points above. Its where you lay out the sort of actions you want your service to have. for example above I have said that I want to allow MetaData to be published. This will essentially create a WSDL which describes the service.

The full config is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <!--Set up the service-->
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SOAPRESTDemoBehavior" name="SOAPRESTDemo">
        <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="SOAPRESTDemoEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ISOAPRESTDemo" />
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ISOAPRESTDemo" />
      </service>
    </services>


    <!--Define the behaviours-->
    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SOAPRESTDemoBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SOAPRESTDemoEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for simple and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

here's an example of it, it carries some properties of the connection of the service.

```
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="WcfServiceNetMSMQ.Service1Behavior">
 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
 <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
</behavior>
```

Notice that the `name` in this service behavior corresponds to the one you specified earlier.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error with Behavior name is not setup correctly.

The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://blabla.com/WebService/Processor.svc'.
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service 'http://blabla.com/WebService/Processor.svc'.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.