# PHP to WCF with SoapClient - Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, php, web-services, soap, soap-client

I have a soap svc web service and these are my WS methods:

**StoreService.svc.cs**

```
namespace StoreServices
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class StoreService : IStoreService
    {
        public bool SaveCarData(Car car)
        {
            //Some code
        }
    }
}
```

**IStoreService.cs**

```
namespace StoreServices
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IStoreService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/SaveCarData", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        bool SaveCarData(Car car);
    }
}
```

In my WS web.config I already turned up all the buffers to send and receive big data:

**web.config**

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" maxRequestLength ="2147483647" executionTimeout="999999"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" receiveTimeout="10:00:00" closeTimeout="10:00:00"
          sendTimeout="10:00:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="10:00:00" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://myDomain.pt/WStore/StoreService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
        contract="StoreServices.IStoreService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

My client call my service like this:

```
<?php

ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 360000);

class Car
{
  public $Id=0;
  public $Name="My new car";
  public $Description="";
  public $ImageBase64="";
}


$car_toInsert = new Car();
$requestParams = array('car' => $car_toInsert);

try {
    $time_start = microtime(true);

    $client = new SoapClient('http://myDomain.pt/WStore/StoreService.svc?wsdl', 
        array('encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1', 'keep_alive' => true,
            'trace' => 1,
            'exceptions'=> 1,
            'connection_timeout'=> 3600));

    $response = $client->SaveCarData($requestParams);   
    print_r($response);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $time_request = (microtime(true)-$time_start);
    if(ini_get('default_socket_timeout') < $time_request) {
        //Timeout error!
        print_r("request time bigger");
    } else {
        //other error
        //$error = $e->getMessage();
        print_r($e->getMessage());
    }
} 
?>
```

My client already turned on his "buffers" like said in [here](http://galleryproject.org/node/40504).

Now the problem is: when my client send a "short" `Car.ImageBase64` string this works just fine, but when the `Car.ImageBase64` string is huge he can communicate with my WS and get this error: ***Request Entity Too Large***

**Short ImageBase64 example:**

```
class Car
{
  public $Id=0;
  public $Name="My new car";
  public $Description="";
  public $ImageBase64="data:image/jpg;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7";
}
```

**Huge ImageBase64 example:**

*my ImageBase64 string example is too big to insert in this question form. Please insert the url "http://d3eaqdewfg2crq.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/carousel/main-reporting/report.png" in [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html#ad-output) and encode to base64.*

What is the problem and how can we solve this? I have simulated my client communication to test some things and I figured out he is making a http GET request. I think this can be the problem and I want to change it to http POST. How can I do this in the PHP code?

[image: Error php request headers]

I also tried to change my web config like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453841/what-is-the-behaviorconfiguration-attribute-of-service) but I got a "**SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find...**” error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! After many search and modifications I finally solved the problem with a new web.config changing. How I have not client endpoints but server endpoints for all clients that communicates with my WS. I also needed to create a new service (svc and interface files in the same WCF project) and change my web.confi to this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IStoreService" 
                 receiveTimeout="10:00:00" 
                 closeTimeout="10:00:00" 
                 sendTimeout="10:00:00" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 openTimeout="10:00:00"/>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceIntegration" 
                 receiveTimeout="10:00:00" 
                 closeTimeout="10:00:00" 
                 sendTimeout="10:00:00" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 openTimeout="10:00:00">
                  <readerQuotas
                      maxDepth="2147483647"
                      maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                      maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
     <service name="StoreServices.StoreService" behaviorConfiguration="StoreServicesBehavior"/>

      <service name="StoreServices.IntegrationService" behaviorConfiguration="IntegrationServicesBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  contract="StoreServices.IIntegrationService"
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceIntegration" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>

    </services>
    <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="StoreServicesBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>

        <behavior name="IntegrationServicesBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" 
            relativeAddress="./StoreServices/StoreService.svc" 
            service="StoreServices.StoreService" />
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
```